# TYPO3 Form send via JQuery.submit()

Tags: jquery, ajax, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have an typo3 form (action="update") which should be sended via jquery.

Form looks like this:

`<f:form action="update" name="note" object="{note}">
 <textarea class="form-control gettooltip" rows="1" placeholder="Kommentar" title="Kommentar zur Note">{note.kommentar}</textarea>
</f:form>`

Comment: Okay i've got a new problem! Now I can send the form with jqury send no problem but then typo3 says me: `Required argument "note" is not set.`


My code looks like this:

`<f:for each="{notes}" as="note">
<f:form action="update" name="note" object="{note}">
 <textarea class="form-control gettooltip" rows="1" placeholder="Kommentar" title="Kommentar zur Note">{note.kommentar}</textarea>
</f:form>
</f:for>`

Comment: okay I think its a problem because I've added the edit form in the list template??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to warn you to not follow our team way, when you try to use some custom AJAX dispatcher, then switch to different pageType, after that to eID or whatever. **My recommended way to do AJAX** calls within TYPO3 is to use [EXT:typoscript_rendering](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/typoscript_rendering)

Find this [article](http://insight.helhum.io/post/104880845705/dont-use-eid-ajax-dispatchers-for-your-extbase) from extension's author, which has links to root causes and usage example.

And a Github [repository](https://github.com/helhum/typoscript_rendering).