# Foreign Key to TYPO3 Frontend User

Tags: foreign-keys, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, extension-builder3

How can I set a ForeignKey to the TYPO3 FrontendUsers in the Extension Builder?

Do I have to set the param map to existing table? oder make a relation?

What I want to do:

I've got a Model (People) with its own fields and values. and now I want to have a new Releation between this Model and the TYPO3 FE Users

PeopleNr = fe_user with uid 123

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note:** *As stated in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27603457/1066240) creating relations between tables/models doesn't require adding foreign keys*

I'm not quite sure what do you need it for, but here's description of two most common cases (screenshot shows how to achieve each case with Extension Builder)

#### Creating relation to `FrontendUser` model / `fe_user` table

In TYPO3 ver. 6.2 `fe_user` has a model as well: `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser`, you can just add this as common relation in Builder modeling tool (*fig. 2 at screenshot*) in the field `\Fully\Qualified\Classname` (you need to `Show advanced fields` to set it (*fig. 1*) use this `FrontendUser` and it will create proper `SQL` and `TCA` definitions.

#### Real extending `FrontendUser` (FU) model

On the other hand if your `People`* model just extends the `fe_user` table, because you want to reuse existing fe_user table for your people, you can also **extend** `FrontendUser` model for real (*fig. 3*) in that case you'll inherit all getters, setters from FU etc. and you won't need to write them yourself.

In such case your model will be a separate type of `fe_user`, the discriminator field is by default: `tx_extbase_type` and builder will add new type like `Tx_YourExt_Employee`

*`*` note: For model names you should use singular form i.e `Man` instead of `People`*

[image: builder sample]

Comment: Thanks. I've done this. (2) so next step I gonna try to get the relation. hope that works fine ;) 


sorry for offtopic i've got anoter problem probably you can help me also that would be really nice ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598919/typo3-form-send-via-jquery-submit