# Get list of Frontend Usergroups

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I've tried to get a list with all Frontend Usergroups

I've tried this:

```
    /**
 * Protected Variable FrontendUserGroupRepository wird mit NULL initialisiert.
 *
 * @var \ReRe\Rere\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserGroupRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $FrontendUserGroupRepository = NULL;
```

and then this

```
 $feUserGroups = $this->frontendUserGroupRepository->findAll();
```

But the list is always empty, even if there are 2 usergroups in the database.

Update ... i tried this as repository

```
class FrontendUserGroupRepository extends \Typo3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserGroupRepository {

     // Example for repository wide settings
    public function initializeObject() {
        /** @var $defaultQuerySettings Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Typo3QuerySettings */
        $defaultQuerySettings = $this->objectManager->get('Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Typo3QuerySettings');
        // go for $defaultQuerySettings = $this->createQuery()->getQuerySettings(); if you want to make use of the TS persistence.storagePid with defaultQuerySettings(), see #51529 for details

        // don't add the pid constraint
        $defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
        // don't add fields from enablecolumns constraint
        $defaultQuerySettings->setRespectEnableFields(FALSE);
        // don't add sys_language_uid constraint
        $defaultQuerySettings->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);
        $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($defaultQuerySettings);
    }

}
```

but I got this error:

> Could not analyse class:Typo3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FEUserGroupsRepositry maybe not loaded or no autoloader

I've added the a new dependecy injection and reinstalled the module ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default each Extbase repository has flag `respectStoragePage` set to true, that means that user groups need to be placed at the page which is configured as **Default storage PID** in your exts constants, anyway as I saw you probably don't include it at all.

In such case you need to create own repository extending FrontendUserGroupRepository and then initialize it without respecting the storage.

It's described in [official docs](http://wiki.typo3.org/Default_Orderings_and_Query_Settings_in_Repository).

Edit: if you extending some model/repo in your extension Builder automatically limits your repo to objects of your type only, i.e. by adding in TS mapping:

```
 recordType = Tx_Rere_FrontendUserGroup
```

So if you want to get access to all records of extended model, just remove the `recordType` from `ext_typoscript_setup.txt` completely (don't forget to clear system cache).

Comment: @biesior: You might add an information about ```module.tx_myext``` being used for Backend modules.

Comment: I've added my new repository code with exception above .. whats going wrong?

Comment: thanks besior very stupid copy paste mistake ... really stupid ... to much time in my cellar office

Comment: corrected the code above .. but the problem extists as well.

Comment: okay solved some problems ... 
but now I got this error:
`Could not find class definition for name "ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup". This could be caused by a mis-spelling of the class name in the class definition. `


It's clear why I got this but how can I resolve it?

Comment: Create this model extending with `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup`

Comment: I've created the Model `ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup`and extended the original FrontendUsrGroup Modul ... 

and now it says no Table in database `#1247602160: Table 'typo3.tx_rere_domain_model_frontendusergroup' doesn't exist (More information)` Do I have to edit the TypoScript also??

Comment: @Felix some time ago I described you a difference between extending model in Builder and making the relation. Check this clue for solution, curently I'm AFK

Comment: thats right. sorry forgotten it. I've done lit like figure 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601254/foreign-key-to-typo3-frontend-user ... but the return value is NULL ... but there are 2 entries in database :(

Comment: I asked if have you got your code in some git repo, sorry ;)